# Is it consistent that $V\not =L$ but $V_\alpha=L_\alpha$ for some $\alpha>\omega$?

Tags: set-theory

This is a question about [constructible universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe). Notation follows the wiki entry. $V=L$ is the statement that every set is constructible.

Is it consistent with ZFC that $V\not =L$ but $V_\alpha=L_\alpha$ for some $\alpha>\omega$? If it is consistent, then what restrictions it puts on $\alpha$?

Comment: It might be worth making the body of the question self-contained (copy the title into it), and while I agree that for anyone in the set theory tag there's no need to add any details to it, it might be fruitful to explain the notation in a couple of sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

Start with $V=L$, pick your favourite $\alpha$ for which $V_\alpha=L_\alpha$, and consider the forcing that adds a new subset to $\alpha^+$. This forcing will not add any subsets of rank $<\alpha^+$, so in particular $V_\alpha\models V=L$ and is therefore equal to $L_\alpha$.

If $\alpha$ is strongly inaccessible, you can just add a subset to $\alpha$ itself, and this will preserve strong inaccessibility. Depending on the specifics of the forcing you may or may not preserve stronger large cardinal axioms as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the forcing notion can be $\text{Fn}_{\alpha^+}(\alpha^+,2)$ and we choose generic filter $G$ so that $\bigcup G$ is not in the ground model.

Comment: Oh, the above forcing notion only works for cardinals. How to do the ordinal cases?

Comment: @accddj in order to have $V_\alpha=L_\alpha$, $\alpha$ needs to be a cardinal. A $\beth$-fixed-point cardinal, in fact. (This is just by comparing the cardinality of both sides.)

Comment: @accddj: Also, adding new sets to an ordinal is the same as adding sets to its cardinal. Bijections transfer subsets.